# I moved the Javascript to an external file, and it stopped working

Tags: javascript, django-1.5

I'm working in Django, on a template that features a Google Map.

The Google Map requires a lot of Javascript, which I had placed at one point of the template right before the `div` element in which the map was located. (It just happened to work out this way because of the way pages extend eachother and how I compartmentalized them). Everything worked great.

I decided that the Javascript was taking up so much space and made the page cluttered, so I cut all it out of the template and replaced it with one line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'ManagerApp/js/gMapsSettings.js' %}"></script>
```

Suddenly, the map on the page no longer works. I reset the server, and still no results. I know the path is correct because I have another `.js` in the same location, referenced one line above this one and an alert I set in it, goes off as the page loads.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: @NickDugger Ah yes... there are errors because parts of the code included Django tags, i.e. `{% for users in allUsers %}`  Is there any way to include this in external Javascript?

Comment: From the looks of it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339529/using-django-template-tags-inside-external-javascript) I'd say not really, unless you do as they say, and either render it as a template, or insert it as plain text into the body.